# getting dynamic element id for jQuery, PHP

Tags: php, jquery

```
$cour = mysql_sql('SELECT c.id, c.category, cc.name, c.fullname,c.summary FROM 
mdl_course c, mdl_course_categories cc WHERE c.id = cc.course');

echo '<table>';                       
foreach($cour as $cou) 
{
    $coursename = $cou->fullname;
    $courseid = $cou->id;
    $summary = $cou->summary;
    echo '
        <tr style="border:1px solid #BACC82;">  
            <td><a onclick="ShowHide(); return false;">'.$coursename.'</a></td>
        </tr>
        <!--SHOW AND HIDE DIV-->
        <div id="enclosure" style="display:none;">'.$summary.'</div>
    ';
}
echo '</table>';
```

JQUERY IN THE SAME FILE

```
function ShowHide() {
    $('#enclosure').animate({"height": "toggle"}, {duration: 1000});
}
```

Here in my code and its working only for the first row.
I want to pass $courseid to Jquery, so that wherever if i click on coursename, it should display current course summary and if i click the next coursename, the previous summary should hide and show the present one. Could anyone help me a clear code.

Comment: consider using class in place of id. You can have only one unique id in the html page.

Comment: This is working fine and but where should i pass $courseid, it displays unique place(its ok) but only with one courseid

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask a new question instead of editing this one and invalidating its answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do it in the following way:

```
$cour = mysql_sql('SELECT c.id, c.category, cc.name, c.fullname,c.summary FROM 
mdl_course c, mdl_course_categories cc WHERE c.id = cc.course');

echo '<table>';                       
foreach($cour as $cou) 
{
    $coursename = $cou->fullname;
    $courseid = $cou->id;
    $summary = $cou->summary;
    echo '
        <tr style="border:1px solid #BACC82;">  
            <td>
                <a onclick="ShowHide('.$courseid.'); return false;">'.$coursename.'</a>
                <!--SHOW AND HIDE DIV-->
                <div id="enclosure_'.$courseid.'" style="display:none;">'.$summary.'</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    ';
}
echo '</table>';
```

The javascript:

```
function ShowHide(id) {
    $('#enclosure_'+ id).animate({"height": "toggle"}, {duration: 1000});
}
```

I made every element with a unique ID by give the div a enclose_{ID} because the id from the database is unique, every div aswell.

**EDIT**: see update for the HTML

Comment: And if you change your HTML, please move the div to a allowed poistion. Right behind the closing </a> for example. As far as I know it is not allowed between </tr> and <tr>

Comment: its not valid yes, but i was only showing a solution for his problem and not his invalid HTML.. but i changed mine in a valid HTML. This should solve his problem, but i cannot insure him that his animate effect would do much.. because tables and animation height not going together very well.. i would say make your own table with `div`'s

Comment: Hi Tricker Thank you for your code, but it shows in the wrong way, like when I click the current coursename, it shows correctly, and when i click the next coursename, the current one isn't hiding and not showing the new one

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have several elements with the same Id on page. Select by class name or rather apply more sophisticated selector like `$('#yourtableid div')` if that divs are only divs in your table

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using inline JavaScript: onclick="ShowHide", attach an event with jQuery:

```
<td><a class="show-hide-action">'$coursename.'</a></td>
<div class="enclosure" style="display:none;">'.$summary.'</div>
```

Make the enclosure ID a CLASS, you can not duplicate IDs.

```
$(function() {                                // encapsulate in document.ready
  $('.show-hide-action').click(function() {   // bind action
    $(this)                                   // 'this' is the clicked element
      .parent()                               // parent should be the TD
      .next(".enclosure")                      // select the corresponding .enclosure  
      .animate({"height": "toggle"}, {duration: 1000});
  });
});
```

This is untested code, but should give you the gist of it.

Answer (score -1):

```
    <!--SHOW AND HIDE DIV-->
<div class="enclosure" style="display:none;">'.$summary.'</div>
```

Jquery:

```
    function ShowHide() {
      $('.enclosure').animate({"height": "toggle"}, {duration: 1000});
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but when i click the first row, it displays all the course summaries at a time